# Refactor this Python code to iterate over a container

Tags: python, django, refactoring, iterator

Surely there is a better way to do this?

```
results = []
if not queryset is None:
    for obj in queryset:
        results.append((getattr(obj,field.attname),obj.pk))
```

The problem is that sometimes queryset is None which causes an exception when I try to iterate over it. In this case, I just want result to be set to an empty list. This code is from a Django view, but I don't think that matters--this seems like a more general Python question.

**EDIT:** I turns out that it was my code that was turning an empty queryset into a "None" instead of returning an empty list. Being able to assume that queryset is always iteratable simplifies the code by allowing the "if" statement to be removed. The answers below maybe useful to others who have the same problem, but cannot modify their code to guarantee that queryset is not "None".

Comment: There's nothing that can be improved about this -- as shown.  If you can explain why "sometimes" queryset is None, then perhaps we can help with that.

Comment: do you have a typo in the last line? append takes one argument, and numbers of closing and open brackets do not correspond to each other.

Comment: Yes, fixed the typo. The queryset is being set from a database search, and if there are no results, it seems to be set to None.

Comment: Turns out that I can easily modify the code so that queryset returns an empty list instead of None which neatly solves the problem. :) The solutions posted here are interesting and could be useful in the future though.

Comment: @gerdemb: Please update your question with what you were doing wrong in creating the queryset and post your answer with what you are now doing right.

Comment: Ditto S.Lott, it would be useful if you update your question to show what the real problem was and how you solved it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
results = [(getattr(obj, field.attname), obj.pk) for obj in queryset or []]
```

Comment: I don't recall the operator priority exactly, but you might have to put:

for obj in (queryset or [])

Comment: @Gabriel: parentheses are unnecessary. Though you might  add them for readability if you rarely see such code.

Answer (score 8):

How about

```
for obj in (queryset or []):
    # Do your stuff
```

It is the same as J.F Sebastians suggestion, only not implemented as a list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, Django managers have a "none" queryset that you can use to avoid gratuitous None-checking.  Using it to ensure you don't have a null queryset may simplify your code.

```
if queryset is None:
    queryset = MyModel.objects.none()
```

References:

- [Django documentation on none()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#none)
- [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)

Answer (score 1):

you can use list comprehensions, but other than that I don't see what you can improve

```
result = []
 if queryset:
     result = [(getattr(obj, field.attname), obj.pk) for obj in queryset]
```

Comment: One notice: `if queryset` evaluates queryset and retrieve all underlying data

Comment: i'm sorry, but i don't see how my snippet is any different in this respect from the original code

Comment: Daevaorn: it doesn't retrieve all underlying data, in boolean context it's smart enough to just do a COUNT().

Comment: SilentGhost: your version is less efficient.  "queryset is None" just does a Python object identity comparison, whereas "if queryset" evaluates queryset in a boolean context, which forces a SQL COUNT() query (since a queryset that returns no rows also evaluates to False).